# UTF8 encoding not working when reading from PO files in CakePHP 2.3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, utf-8, character-encoding, web

My site is to be in Turkish, and I've created a locale file in `app/Locale/tur/LC_MESSAGES/default.po`

I've set the configuration Configure::write('Config.language','tr'); in my App controller's before filter. It is ready from the intended po file. However the characters when shown are getting garbled. Example:  Ürünler shown as `�r�nler`

I've set character encoding to utf8 in page headers. Database encoding works fine. If I echo `Ürünler` as it is in a string it still works fine. However its only when it comes from PO file that it is creating problems.

I am developing my site in CakePHP 2.3.2. I've done many many multilingual sites in Cake but never faced this problem.

My PO file is okay as I even tried one of the PO files that is working fine in my past projects, it still doesn't work.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: the ENTIRE rendering pipeline must be the same charset, or you'll get mangled text that way. might be utf8 in the db and at the client-side page level, but if (say) the DB link ISN'T, then you get the corruption.

Comment: Hi Marc, everything I could see is already set to same charset. Db, client side page headers, db link. Could there be anything other than these also?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to set your headers to utf8. You also need to save files that contain utf8 chars as utf8. So check your file and make sure this is the case (utf8 without bom!).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that default.po is saved in Unicode(utf-8)

Dreamweaver CS6 - Open file -> Modify -> Page Properties -> Document encoding (select Unicode (UTF-8)